# How to share settings across an application?

Tags: ember.js

I have a main page listing some categories / subcategories. Whenever a subcategory is clicked, the action `openSubcategory` is triggered:

```
// routes/application.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    userSelections: Ember.inject.service('user-selections'),

    actions: {
        openSubcategory: function(categoryId, subcategoryId) {
            var userSelections = this.get('userSelections');
            userSelections.set('category', categoryId);
            userSelections.set('subcategory', subcategoryId);
            this.transitionTo('filter-categories');
        },
    }
});
```

To pass the selections to the corresponding controller, I am using a service:

```
// services/user-selections.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    category: null,
    subcategory: null,
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.set('category', null);
        this.set('subcategory', null);
    },
});
```

Which is evaluated in:

```
// controllers/filter-categories.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    userSelections: Ember.inject.service('user-selections'),
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.get('userSelections');  // We need to get it so that we can observe it?
        // We can not declare the observers, because we need to make sure userSelections is first read
        this.addObserver('userSelections.category', function() {
            Ember.run.once(this, 'refreshProducts');
        });
        this.addObserver('userSelections.subcategory', function() {
            Ember.run.once(this, 'refreshProducts');
        });
    },
    actions: {
        changedCategory: function(selectedCategory) {
            this.set('selectedCategory', selectedCategory);
            this.get('userSelections').set('category', selectedCategory.value);
        },
        changedSubcategory: function(selectedSubcategory) {
            this.set('selectedSubcategory', selectedSubcategory);
            this.get('userSelections').set('subcategory', selectedSubcategory.value);
        },
    },
    refreshProducts: function() {
        var userSelections = this.get('userSelections'),
            category = userSelections.get('category'),
            subcategory = userSelections.get('subcategory');
        var products = this.store.filter('product', function(product) {
            var catId = parseInt(product.get('category').get('id')),
                subcatId = parseInt(product.get('subcategory').get('id'));
            if (category && catId !== category) {
                return false;
            }
            if (subcategory && subcatId !== subcategory) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
        this.set('model', products);
    },
});
```

Observing the `userSelections` (after some hacking, as seen in the comments) works: the actions are properly triggering the `refreshProducts` method. But it seems the method is not triggered when coming from the application route, probably because the `controllers/filter-categories` is not yet initialized.

(*) According to the [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/object-model/observers/) there are lots "issues" observing services.

- [Observers and asynchrony](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/object-model/observers/#toc_observers-and-asynchrony)
- [Observers and object initialization](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/object-model/observers/#toc_observers-and-object-initialization)
- [Unconsumed Computed Properties Do Not Trigger Observers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/object-model/observers/#toc_unconsumed-computed-properties-do-not-trigger-observers)
- "The injected property is lazy; the service will not be instantiated until the property is explicitly called" ([link](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/applications/services/))

As a result, code needs to be written in a difficult to understand way. 
Is there a better pattern to share data between routes / controllers than using a service?

### EDIT

These are my templates:

```
// partials/categories.hbs (used on the application.hbs template)

{{#each model.categories as |category| }}
<div class="categories-list row">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="category-name centered">
      <span class="bg-left"></span>
      <span class="bg-center uppercase">{{category.name}}</span>
      <span class="bg-right"></span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="category owl-carousel">
    {{#each category.subcategories as |subcategory| }}
    <div class="category-item">
      <a href="{{subcategory.link}}">
        <div class="category-icon">
          <img src="{{subcategory.image}}">
        </div>
        <h4 class="capitalize" {{action "openSubcategory" category.id subcategory.id}}>{{subcategory.name}}</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

And:

```
// filter-categories.hbs

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Our Vault</h2>
      <legend>Filter products by category / subcategory</legend>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <form class="form-inline portfolio-form">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          {{#power-select options=optionsCategory selected=selectedCategory onchange=(action "changedCategory") as |category|}}
            {{category.text}}
          {{/power-select}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          {{#power-select options=optionsSubcategory selected=selectedSubcategory onchange=(action "changedSubcategory") as |subcategory|}}
            {{subcategory.text}}
          {{/power-select}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" {{action "clearSelections" id}}><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Clear Filters</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    {{partial "products"}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the templates? So that we can see how things are setup in the template?

Comment: Is there a reason you have the action `openSubcategory` in `application` route instead of the controller? If you move this code to the `application` controller, and then move the code from your service to another controller, let's say `controllers/user-selections`, then you can use [`Ember.inject.controller`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_controller) similarly to how you were using the service and inject this new controller as the intermediary between `controllers/application` and `controllers/filter-categories`

Comment: @nem, thanks for the ideas, but not sure this applies. First, there is no user-selections route, so it is a bit awkward to define a controller for a route which does not exist (I think of controllers as route-related, correct me if I am wrong). Instead, a service seems like a more application-wide method of storing and sharing data. Currently I want to set some selections in the application route to be used in the filter-categories route, but soon I will be using the same pattern to share the same data between more routes. The same selections can be set and evaluated in different places.

Comment: Actually, controllers are perfectly fine to be standalone, in fact, before services, controllers were already used for this purpose (i.e. the deprecated [`needs`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) property). My suggestion was there since you mentioned that services still have some bugs (although I haven't had any issues with them). Another cleanup you can make perhaps is to use `Ember.observer` and have `userSelections.category` and `userSelections.subcategory` as properties instead of manually calling `this.addObserver` inside `init`.

Comment: @nem: I can not `Ember.observer` on a service because it is lazy ...

Comment: Oh ok, but you can still combine the two observers as on at least...

Comment: @nem: actually, I tried to combine both observers but did not succeed. I was trying: `this.addObserver('userSelections.category', 'userSelection.subcategory', function() {});`, but it does not work. Actually, according to the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_addObserver), it is not possible to specify more than one property to `addObserver` (but [it is possible](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/object-model/observers/) with `Ember.observer`! - Ember is not very consistent)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're avoiding the use of [dynamic segments](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments)? If not you can pass the category and subcategory as dynamic segments when using `transitionTo('filter-categories')`, an added benefit  would be that this route will become linkable :)

So for eg. you should define your `filter-categories` route like this:

```
// router.js
...
this.route('filter-categories', { path: 'filter-categories/:category_id/:subcategory_id' });
...
```

Now in your `routes/filter-categories.js` router you could do:

```
// routes/filter-categories
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    // you can put your `refreshProducts` logic in here
    // (I mean in this router not literally in this method)
    // and return the products model or whatever you want
    // I will just return an object with the ids for simplicity
    return {
      categoryId: params.category_id,
      subcategoryId: params.subcategory_id
    };
  }
...
```

And now in your application route:

```
// routes/application.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        openSubcategory: function(categoryId, subcategoryId) {
            this.transitionTo('filter-categories', categoryId, subcategoryId);
        }
    }
});
```

edit:

If you don't always have an `categoryId` and `subcategoryId` you can use [query parameters](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/routing/query-params/) instead of dynamic segments.

Comment: Thanks! This does not answer my question, but it is something I want to explore. I would still like to know how to share data application wide though.

Comment: I think I would use query parameters, since I indeed do not have always a category / subcategory. One question about this: my `filter-categories` route has also some dropdowns to change the filters. Can I update the query parameters without re-transitioning to the `filter-categories`. I am not sure, since the query params are in the URL too.